# HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlstring) gets snagged on links

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a HTML text box popup from my script in Google Docs, and found that my function was running perfectly when I downloaded a local version of the output, but had mistakes in the text box output that appeared.

```js
var html5 = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlstring)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(800)
  .setHeight(500);
var mycontent = html5.getContent(); // for checking in debugger
DocumentApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html5, 'Markdown output');
```

My text is:

> Text goes here until a “quoted [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link)”, at which point the link is lost!

...which my script processes (as confirmed from the debugger) to a string variable `mdstring`

> `Text goes here until a "quoted [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link)", at which point the link is lost!`

By the lines:

```js
var htmlstring =
  '<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">'
  + '</head><pre><textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select()">'
  + mdstring
  + '</textarea></pre></html>';
```

which I can confirm again from the debugger produces a string (newlines added for readability):

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<pre><textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select()">Text goes here until a
"quoted [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link)", at which point the link
is lost!</textarea></pre></html>
```

At this point I stripped the processing away from my script so it literally just set the string as that.

```js
var htmlstring =
  '<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>'
  + '<pre><textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select();">'
  + 'Text goes here until a "quoted [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link)", at which point the link is lost!'
  //  + mdstring
  + '</textarea></pre></html>';
```

Bizarrely, the output then had `></pre></html>` straight after the `https:`

[image]

If I switch back to

```js
var htmlstring =
  '<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><pre><textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select();">'
  + mdstring
  + '</textarea></pre></html>';
```

... then those tags go away

[image]

So I stuck with setting `mdstring` programmatically rather than entering myself... :-/

Anyway, the problem doesn't relate to that (though that's very odd). The problem is that regardless of how it's handling strings there, Google Apps Script's HtmlService class `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()` method is getting snagged on links within quotation marks passed in as `htmlstring`.

Debugger recorded `htmlstr`:

> `<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><pre><textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select();">Text goes here until a "quoted [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link)", at which point the link is lost! </textarea></pre></html>`

Debugger recorded `mycontent`:

> `<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><pre><textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select();">Text goes here until a "quoted [link](https: </textarea></pre></html>`

How can I get my string to render as HTML? It's been really handy for my script (a [Google Docs to markdown converter](https://github.com/lmmx/gdocs2md-html/)) to output within the page, but this bug compromises the ability to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this as [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4922) now, and handled with Javascript rather than `onclick` (an event handler would be set ideally, but set it inline here as proof of concept)

```js
  var htmlstring =
      '<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">'
    + css_style
    + '</head><body><pre><textarea id="md-output" readonly="readonly">'
    + mdstring
    + '</textarea></pre><script type="text/javascript">'
    + 'function mdClick() {'
    + 'var textbox = document.getElementById("md-output");'
    + 'textbox.setAttribute("onclick", "this.focus(); this.select();") }'
    + 'window.onload = mdClick();'
    + '</script></body></html>';
```